# mysql prevent duplicate rows, if field is repeated

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Can I, and if so, how do I prevent mysql from returning duplicate results

```
 SELECT meta_id, post_id, DISTINCT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id='69' AND meta_value LIKE '%iframe%'
```

I want to get just the one row, so ignore any further items if meta_value duplicated!

Putting DISTINCT where it is, returns no results, but query works as expected if removed, so it is obviously wrong to put it there!

Comment: SELECT meta_id, post_id,meta_value  FROM wp_postmeta WHERE post_id='69' AND meta_value LIKE '%iframe%' GROUP BY meta_value

Answer (score 1):

If you want only one result you can use LIMIT in MySql like

```
SELECT meta_id, post_id, DISTINCT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id='69' 
AND meta_value LIKE '%iframe%'
LIMIT 1
```

OR in Sql you can use

```
SELECT TOP 1 meta_id, post_id, DISTINCT meta_value 
FROM wp_postmeta 
WHERE post_id='69' 
AND meta_value LIKE '%iframe%'
```

Comment: Good idea, but I need it to return a unique set, meta_value seems to have duplicates for some reason!

Comment: Then I think you can go with the GROUP BY meta_value as suggested by @laiju in the previous comment.